# In python how to continue a loop after breaking it?

Tags: python

In the following code, I want that when the value in `hist` is zero `0`, then the `j` loop should break, but it should work for last two numbers 7 and 8. hist represents bin values. In my actual code I have to plot graphs using bin values. For `hist[j]==0` I can not plot graph that is why I used break statement. But with the following code I can not plot graphs when hist value is 7 and 8 because once loop breaks I can not check it for value 7 and 8. So how to overcome this problem?

```
hist = [10,0,7,8]  
for j in range(3):
    if hist[j] == 0:
        print("break loop")
        break
    else:
        print("still continue")
        continue`
```

Comment: your question was unclear. It does exactly what you want (break when the value is 0)

Comment: You can't resume a loop after calling `break`. You have to do some other logic depending on what behavior you want to implement.

Comment: just like the code says,  when you encounter a `0`, `break` the loop. So the loop won't continue

Comment: Yes it bearks the loop for hist[j]==0. But it runs j loop only 2 times . I want to run this 4 times for checking last two values of 7 and 7.

Comment: Should i only implement a condition that if hist[j] !=0 perform a certain operation? Should I not use break command here?is it unnecessary?

Comment: You cant continue loop when you put `break`

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to actually `continue` on `hist[j] == 0`.

You don't have to call `continue` explicitly because the loop will go back to the top when it reaches the last line of the code inside it. So again, `continue` is what you are describing:

```
hist = [10,0,7,7]  
for j in range(3):
    if hist[j] == 0:
        print("break loop")
        continue
    else:
        print("still continue")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is

```
hist = [10, 0, 7, 7]
for i in hist:
    if i == 0:
        print("break loop")
        continue 

    print("still continue")
```

---

This can jump over executing `print("still continue")` when `i == 0`.

---

`break` will jump out the `for` loop, `continue` jump back to the loop without executing the statement behind(here is `print("still continue")`) in loop.